# std::map std::priority_queue && lambda comparator

Tags: c++, lambda, priority-queue

Bonjour

I would like to use a map of strings and priority queue with a lamda based custom comparator. I wrote something similar to the code below but it does'nt compile and I believe I almost understand why (any good explainations are more than welcome)

Q : How should I modify the code below such that it compile.

```
auto MyComparator = [](const Person &a, const Person &b) {
    return a.YearOfBirth > b.YearOfBirth;  
};

 std::map<std::string, std::priority_queue<Person, std::vector<Person>, decltype(MyComparator)>> Familly(MyComparator);
```

I did some testing before to come here and the code below code compile and works as expected but I'm not sure to fully understand why.

```
struct MyComparator {
  bool operator()(const Person &a, const Person &b) {
    return a.YearOfBirth > b.YearOfBirth;
  }
};

std::map<std::string, std::priority_queue<Person, std::vector<Person>, MyComparator>> Familly;
```

Note : the code above also works if you use a class rather than a struct (just make sure the operator() is public)

Thaks for your help, Philippe

Comment: Just remove the `(MyComparator)` argument? Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Yes but no. I did it already and it does'nt help.

Comment: Works here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P483eP

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You're right. I use MSVC and it doesn't work (even on godbolt). I'll send a feedback to MSVC team. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
std::map<std::string, std::priority_queue<Person, std::vector<Person>, decltype(MyComparator)>> Familly(MyComparator);
```

you are calling ctor of `std::map`.

If you just use

```
std::priority_queue<Person, std::vector<Person>, decltype(MyComparator)> Familly(MyComparator);
```

it will work.

You need to specify `std::priority_queue` with lambda for every key.

Comment: Point one : It was my understanding and I can't call a constructor of a map with a lambda. Thank you for the confirmation.

Point two : I did that already. In this case the Familly priority queue works fine etc. However in my case, I don't know how to go further and declare a map of strings and Familly (as declared with the lambda comparator). I may be slow this morning...